# Extract filename from string

Tags: regex, string, windows, powershell

i have network path and i need to get the filename to a variable for example:

```
$path1 = '\\192.168.10.10\bla\bla\bla\120\s$\filename.exe'
$path2 = '\\srv\c$\bla\bla\120\s$\file2.exe'
```

i would then want to have

```
$var1 = filename.exe
$var2 = filename.exe
```

I'm not quite sure how it can be done with regex, I want to strip everything but the last '' character and what comes after it
Can anyone assist please?

-- EDIT
Ok, I have found a way but it looks a bit stupid:

```
$temp = $path1.split('\')
$var1 = $temp[$temp.lenth -1]
```

there must be more elegant way for this!

Comment: Surely the second is `$path2` ?

Comment: @ShaharWeiss - there is a builtin PoSh cmdlet that does just exactly what you want. take a look at `Get-Help Split-Path` sometime ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No regex required. You can use [GetFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Path_GetFileName_System_String_):

```
$var1 = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path1)
$var2 = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path2)
```